# ELF Header Magic - Why was 0x7F put in it?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, elf

Every resource I have read concerning the ELF header magic points out that it contains ASCII encoded "ELF", and then briefly mentions that 0x7F is prepended to it without explanation.

Is there a reason for the 0x7F?

Was it meant to avoid conflict with an existing format? Existing standard compliance? Used to detect something concerning the disk or memory?

Comment: *Is there a reason for the 0x7F?* Most likely because [0x7F wasn't "claimed" yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) and it's a nice series of almost all ones in binary that's also not a printable ASCII character (`DEL`).  The added `ELF` (in ASCII) add up to a nice, full 32 bits or four bytes.

Comment: It's plausible. Though while it is the only signature that starts with 0x7F, the handful that start with 0x45 ('E') are pretty exotic and it seems like ELF files still could have started with 'ELF' and added an extra byte for 32 bits.

Comment: Having 32 bits is irrelevant for ELF signature, because the first 16 bytes of the ELF header is supposed to be parsed byte-by-byte, since we don't know the endianness of the file yet (it is written in byte #5).
Being a non-printable character also doesn't explain anything, considering that there's a bunch of other non-printable ASCII characters that could do that job equally well.
Being a nice string of ones – irrelevant as well, since 0xFF has all ones (not just the lower 7 bits), so with that logic it would be even better.

Comment: I deleted my answer. Don't forget to say "thank you" to John Bollinger who complained about it :q  To other readers: Don't expect any more answers from me on Stack. I'm done with this site and it's "community".

Comment: @SasQ sorry i did not get back to you sooner. I appreciated your answer. I was planning on seeing if I could research that angle more then get back to you because it certainly seemed like a valid explanation.

Comment: [ELF Magic meaning of “7f” magic number?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/635156/44425)'

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious, it's [leet](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet).

7F sounds like Elf in leet. The letter L can be represented as 7 in leet. Pronounce the letter L with an F and it sounds like Elf. There couldn't be other byte but 0x7F.

Comment: While an good theory, Leet was not nearly as popular at the time ELF was created. Also the rest of the header is just normal ascii, all leet would look like 0x37F. It seems more likely a functional choice, but if you can point to more evidence  to this, I could be convinced.

Comment: Nearly as popular? What does that even mean? Is there a histogram showing the popularity of Leet over the course of the 4 decades it's been originated (1980s). ELF on the other hand started in 1995, that you can see from the early drafts for version 1.0 of the format reference, later being adopted in 1999 as standard for Unix. The majority of file signature are 4 bytes, followed by 2, followed by an even number of bytes. 0x37F does not fit in one byte, since they already had 3 (ELF).

Comment: A magic number as a functional choice? Is this a joke? How did we survive all these years ignoring the essential, vital function of the first byte being 0x7F? How does Linux manage to execute ELF files without using the most important and functional choice made by the creators of ELF, that is using 0x7F as the first byte of its magic number?

Comment: The ELF Standard was part of SVR4 that was released in 88, so its creation is likely in the mid 80's. It became a standard for many vendors to design to. The magic number can help aid that by making sure legacy hardware did not run the application (instruction 0x7f) or convey endianness.